# How to fetch DateTime from mysql using xdevapi

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

When I select a dateTime field, it gets returned as 6 bytes.  How can I convert it to a time_point or struct tm?

```
mysqlx::Session session( "mysqlx://root:password@127.0.0.1:33060/catalog" );
auto row = session.sql( "select create_time from information_schema.tables order by 1 LIMIT 1" ).execute().fetchOne();
assert( row[0].getType()==8 );//raw type
assert( row[0].getRawBytes().second==6 );//6 bytes
var bytes = row[0].getRawBytes().first;
//e2 0f 08 0c 0a 32 
//2018-08-12 10:50:04
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey I just spend 5 hours tring to figure out the same thing, the solution is to project the `TIME`/`DATE`/`DATETIME` field as a UNIX timestamp *(integer)* in your SQL Statement using [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp).

Then you can easily get the field as [`time_t`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time_t/) (and optionally convert to a [`struct tm`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/)).

```
#include<time.h>

mysqlx::Session session{"mysqlx://root:password@127.0.0.1:33060/catalog"};
auto row = session.sql("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(create_time) FROM information_schema.tables ORDER BY 1 LIMIT 1").execute().fetchOne();
time_t creationTime = (int) row[0];
struct tm* creationTimePoint = localtime(creationTime);
```

Hope this helps. *-Minding*

Comment: I encounter this error when implicitly converting `Conversion from 'mysqlx::Value' to 'time_t' (aka 'long') is ambiguous` and using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` it says that the value cannot be converted to an integer.

Comment: @SagunKho I added an explict cast to my answer, do you still encounter problems? If `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` says it can't convert the field to an integer, it's probably not a time related field.

Comment: the issue was that the column was nullable and the value was null. It could not be converted to anything so I had to check the type using `row[0].getType() > 0`. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Thanks, originally I casted to a string but UNIX_TIMESTAMP is better.  Since the dates are in UTC, I use UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(create_time, '+00:00', 'SYSTEM')).